# How to detect if enemy is in the same lane as player in a 2d grid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have the position of the enemy and the player. I want to know if they're in the same lane, that is, the enemy should be ahead/behind the player, either horizontally or vertically. How can I go about implementing this?

I thought of doing a raycast in both horizontal and vertical directions to check if there's an enemy, but I don't want to do this because it will be too inefficient, since I already cast an overlap sphere to find the enemy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your explanation this seems enought:

```
if (player.position.y == enemy.position.y or player.position.x == enemy.position.x)
        sameLane = true;
```

Comment: Since `Vector3` contains `float`s, if to use this solution, one needs to change it into range checks, and define how much error do you allow for the ranges. For example, `Math.Abs(player.position.y - enemy.position.y) <= yError || Math.Abs(player.position.x - enemy.position.x) <= xError`